# Como Popular imagem no Gridview?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em `Asp.NET`, com `Entity Framework` e usando o banco de dados `Oracle` e é o seguinte estou fazendo o upload da imagem por um `button` e salvando no banco de dados com o tipo `BLOB` até ai tudo certo, mas preciso que a imagem apareça na tela junto com informações de outra tabela chamada `PRODUTOS`, estava pensando em popular linha por linha com `DataTable`, mas por não consegui.

**Banco de dados com a imagem BLOB**

> [image: Banco de dados com a imagem BLOB]

**Entity**

[image: Entinty]

**GridView com imagem**

> [image: GridView com imagem]

***Gridview Renderizado no browser***

> [image: Gridview Renderizado no browser]

```
private void carregarImagem()
{
        dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("nome");
        dt.Columns.Add("valor_unit");
        dt.Columns.Add("imagem1");

        ProjetoContext bd = new ProjetoContext();
        List<PRODUTO> produtos = bd.PRODUTOes.ToList();
        List<IMG_PRODUTO> imagem = bd.IMG_PRODUTO.ToList();

        foreach (PRODUTO pr in produtos)
        {

            IMG_PRODUTO im = bd.IMG_PRODUTO.Find(pr.ID_IMAGEM);
            if (im != null && pr.ID_IMAGEM != 0)
            {
                //Image img = (Image)GridProdutos.Rows[1].Cells[4].FindControl
                byte[] byteImagem = im.IMAGEM;
                string img64Frente = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImagem);
                string imagemDataUrl = 
                  String.Format("data:image/png;base64, {0}", img64Frente);
                //img.ImageUrl = imagemDataUrl;
                dt.Rows.Add(pr.ID, pr.NOME, pr.VALOR_UNIT, imagemDataUrl);
            }
        }

        GridProdutos.DataSource = dt;
        GridProdutos.DataBind();

}
```

**CODIGO HTML**

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridProdutos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" OnRowCommand ="GridProdutos_RowCommand" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="GridProdutos_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound ="GridProdutos_RowDataBound">
        <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="id" HeaderText="Index" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="nome" HeaderText="Nome do Produto" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="valor_unit" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="Valor Unitario" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100" Height="100" />
                    <asp:Button ID ="btnAdiciona" runat="server" CommandName="AddItem" Text="Add Carrinho" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Se poderia colocar o código HTML que foi gerado?

Comment: pronto, coloquei o HTML

Comment: Na imagem1 não faltou passar o comando para carregar a informação. ?

Comment: Teste ai `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100" Height="100" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("imagem1") %>' />`

Comment: Ué, deu sim kkkk, você pode me explicar como resolveu isso ?

Comment: Eu olhei o seu código e estava faltando passar a informação para o controler carregar ... se fez o código correto, mas, na hora de chamar na tela não passou a variável para carregar os itens! se funcionou blz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom o comando é bem simples, código a disposição.

Asp.net - Web Form
para dar upload

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUp" runat="server" Width="348px" />
```

Inserir no banco de dados - BackEnd

```
                    img.IMAGEM = FileUp.FileBytes;
                    img.DESCRICAO = cxNome.Text;
                    img.ID = TotalImg;
                    bd.IMG_PRODUTO.Add(img);
```

recuperar a imagem

```
                    byte[] byteImagem = im.IMAGEM;
                    string imagConvert = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImagem);
                    string imagemDataUrl = String.Format("data:imagem/png;base64, {0}", imagConvert);
```

Crédito ao @Virgilio Novic pela resposta